# Find the equation which roots are $\alpha, -\beta$ if $\alpha, \beta$ be the roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

Tags: quadratics

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be the roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $a>0$ where $a, b, c\in \mathbb{R}$. We need to find an equation which roots are $\alpha, -\beta$.

My Trial:

Now $\alpha+\beta=-\frac{b}{a}$ and $\alpha\beta=\frac{c}{a}$. 
Since $(\alpha-\beta)^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha\beta=\frac{b^2}{a^2}-4\frac{c}{a}$ therefore $\alpha-\beta=\pm \sqrt{\frac{b^2-4ac}{a^2}}$ and $\alpha(-\beta)=-\frac{c}{a}$.

hence the required equation is 
$x^2\pm \sqrt{\frac{b^2-4ac}{a^2}}x-\frac{c}{a}=0$ i.e. $ax^2\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}x-c=0$.

I got stuck here. I do not know how to identify which sign is appropriate here. Please help.

Comment: Hint: $\alpha+\beta=-\frac{b}{a}$ and $\alpha\beta=\frac{c}{a}$.

Comment: There are two solutions in general, because we don't know which of the two roots of the original equation is $\alpha$ and which is $\beta$.

Comment: You can't, if $(\alpha,\beta)$ are the roots, so do $(\beta,\alpha)$. In your final equation, one sign is for the pair $(\alpha,-\beta)$, the other one is for $(\beta,-\alpha)$. You need some way to distinguish $\alpha$ from $\beta$ before you can fix the sign.

Comment: $f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-(-\beta))$ should satisfy your requirements.

Comment: @TonyK, could please comment on my suggestion in the comment above this one? Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance: Take for instance $x^2-3x+2$. Are you going to put $\alpha=1,\beta=2$ in your equation? Or $\alpha=2,\beta=1$?

Comment: @TonyK, thanks for your reply, the objective is to find the function.  as long as f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)=(x-2)(x-1), it would not matter. It is true, as you said, that we can't specify the exact value for each root from the given information, nevertheless, the function can be constructed from the roots.

Comment: @NoChance: You seem to have missed the point entirely. So let me ask you this: what would your answer be for the case $a=1,b=-3,c=2$?

Comment: @TonyK, thank you for your time, you may be correct. My understanding is that the parameters $a,b$ and $c$ are determined by comparing the coefficients of the expansion resulting from $(x-\alpha)(x+\beta)=x^2+(\beta-\alpha)x-\alpha\beta$ leading to $a=1$ and $b=\beta-\alpha$ and $c=-\beta\alpha$ as the only possible values for $a,b$ and $c$. By this the quadratic equation is determined. Apologies for wasting your time, you don't have to spend more effort on it. Thanks again.

Comment: @NoChance: But what is the new $b$? Is it $3-2$, or $2-3$? (_Now_ do you get it?)

Comment: Ahaa! Thanks much I get it now. Well done indeed.